# Laravel Order by in one to many relation with second table column

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, sql-order-by

Hi i have tables with one to many relation

**sectors**

```
id
name
position
```

**seat_plans**

```
id
name
sector_id
```

I just want to select all seat plans order by sectors.position. I tried

```
 $seat_plans = SeatPlan::with(['sector' => function($q){
                                        $q->orderBy('position');
                                        }
                                    ])->get();
```

but it is not working. when i check The SQL it is generating query like

```
select * from seat_plans
```

can anybody please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a custom function for your use case.  Instead try this:

```
$users = DB::table('seat_plans')
            ->join('sectors', 'seat_plans.sector_id, '=', 'sectors.id')
            ->select('seat_plans.*')
            ->orderBy('sectors.position')
            ->get();
```

Comment: can't we do this in Eloquent way

Comment: You did not tag your question with Eloquent.